# Importing/Exporting from .csv to multiple python lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv, export-to-csv

I have two lists, where one is a simple list of values, and the other is a list of lists, each element having two values. How would I separately store both these lists in a single .csv sheet and import it when running another python script?

Here's a sample:

```
list_a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
list_b = [[0,0], [0,0], [0,0], [0,0], [0,0]]
```

I've tried this:

```
with open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as a:
    writer = csv.writer(a)
    writer.writerows(list_a)
    writer.writerows(list_b)
```

but then list_a and list_b are stored on the same column, and list_b values, instead of being (0,0) are stored as (,0,",",0,).

So I tried:

```
writer = csv.writer(a, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

but that gave an error:

```
_csv.Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set
```

so then I did:

```
writer = csv.writer(a, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar='\\')
```

But then I get values like (,0,\,,0,)?

I need it in a format that list_a and list_b can be exported into the .csv file and imported as is and used/modified in the same or other scripts. Where am I going wrong here when exporting, and how can I import this back as lists ito a python script? What's the most pythonic simple way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you please give an example of what you want your output file to look like?

Comment: @Terrornado have u died wats the deal man reply asap

Comment: I don't really mind how the .csv file looks as long as I'm able to import and export the example list_a and list_b given above with no errors :) The file itself will only be used for storage anyways. And yes, @Argus, sorry, it's been a late night and it's currently around 3am in the morning for me. I'll definitely have a look tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: @MylesHollowed But I was thinking of the values of list_a stored in column A row 1 to n values, and same for list_b but in column B. But this really isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example uses izip (instead of zip) to avoid creating a new list and having to keep it in the memory. it also avoids using any loops, so the code is short and concise.<.em>

```
import csv
from itertools import izip

with open('output.csv', 'w') as m:
    writer = csv.writer(m)
    writer.writerows(izip(list_a, list_b))
```

Comment: Does Python 3 have izip in itertools?

Comment: you can use zip in python 3 its same as izip in python 2.7,there is no izip in python 3

Comment: alright, that answers half the question, but how would I go about step 2, as in importing these values to list_a and list_b when running another python script? Thanks, btw.